# Java/Mockito: Set up 'when' for list arg containing element

Tags: java, mockito

I'm having some trouble mocking a method call.

My method signature looks like this:

```
Object myMethod(List<String> myArg)
```

I essentially want to say: 'When myMethod is called with myArg that contains "myString", return some object.' But I can't seem to find a matcher in Mockito that will support this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use hamcrest also, here's an example:

```
import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

Mockito.when(myMethod(Mockito.argThat(Matchers.contains("myString")))).thenReturn(someObject);
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I just had to add a cast to `List<String>` to the result of `argThat()`

Comment: For Mockito >= 2.1.0 you'll need to use  `org.mockito.hamcrest.MockitoHamcrest.argThat` rather than `Mockito.argThat`